# How do I optimize image auto-adjustment on window resize and init

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, resize

I have a page wich can contain up to 8 cards. The card are all 1:1 width/height sizes. The cards must be at least 250px wide and a maximum of 350 pixels wide. But the screen only has place for a couple, so when it reaches the maxmimum it can have without the need to scroll, I hide the last one. I do that with the following code:

```
 function fixsizes(){
    $('.container').each(function(){
          var container = $(this);
          var contents = $(this).find('.card:visible');

          contents.each(function(){
              var marginpaddingwidth = contents.length * 101;
              var availablewidth = parseInt(container.width()) - marginpaddingwidth - 10;
              var width = (availablewidth / contents.length);

              if(width < 251){
                  if(contents.length > 1){
                      contents.last().hide();
                  }

                  fixsizes();
              }
              else if(width > 349){
                  var chidden = container.find('.card:hidden');
                  if(chidden.length != 0){
                      chidden.first().show();
                      fixsizes();
                  }
              } 
              else
              {
                  $(this).css('width', width + 'px');
                  $(this).find('.card-image').css('width', width + 'px').css('height', width + 'px');
              }
          });
      });
  }
```

## [Click to see example](http://jsbin.com/EcoZuwik/2), try and resize your window.

Using the latest Chrome (31), it works perfectly. The only problem is though, that every time I resize my screen, and especially when there is enough place for another card, my whole browser locks up because of the calculations (I think?). And I already am on a high end PC, I wonder what it'll do on an old slow laptop.

Is there any way that I can optimize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't seem to be able to open your JS bin to do some sort of profiling but looking at your code doing recursion within a foreach loop is probably the source of the problem.

I think you should look at triggering the fixsizes() after the window has stopped resizing (using a timeout/similar) and also look into manipulating the widths of the images off the DOM using `detach()`.